How to fetch token metadata on chain?
I am trying to retrieve the metadata for a token only using on-chain method such as getProgramAccounts. Unfortunately I cannot use any other language except Python so I cannot make use of libraries such as @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata, which makes the process a lot easier. I am currently unsure where to start, I will be looking into the Metaplex documentation in the meanwhile in order to maybe get to a solution.
I was hoping someone could maybe lend a hand, not necessarily python code I can use but rather the appropriate account I should be querying, the data structs of these account, their IDLs, what type of bytes offset and data slicing to use with memory comparison when I do getProgramAccounts calls and general tips on how I can retrieve token metadata on-chain. Or if someone maybe has another method which works as well.

You could use the DAS API and make use of the fetchAsset RPC call.
More info, https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/get-asset
The examples are in JS, but I think converting them to Python should be easy

I currently use this for my project but I want to move away from relying on an external API. I want a purely on chain solution. Thank you for your suggestion anyways!

could you elaborate on what you mean by on-chain. token metadata is stored offchain, except the name and symbol.  What do you need from the token metadata?

By on-chain I just mean using very fundamental methods to retrieve information from the blockchain without using any third party api or module. I just need name and symbol at the moment.
As I understood it, the Metaplex Metadata is stored as a PDA of the mint account of a token, so wouldn't the metadata be stored onchain?

you'll need to fetch the account data and deserialize it using a typed Metadata interface, this guide is for TS/JS https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-dev-101-deserializing-account-data-on-solana

I am aware I have to deserialise account data but I'm unsure of the size of each field in the interface since I would have to reconstruct the interface as a struct in python with all the relevant data fields and their sizes. But I'm sure I'll figure that out on my own. Thanks for your responses anyways.
